# If python is making a copy of an object, how to stop it?

Tags: python, copy

I am coding a program to find the best week schedule of driving classes, 
"jazda" - Polish for driving lesson (singular). 
"jazdy" - means "driving lessons" (plural). 

I have `class Student` and `class Jazda`

after appending Student object and creating him an atribute it no longer exists on different reference.

This is how i store schedule data

self.dict_schedule = { "monday":[ < Jazda7-9>, < Jazda9-11>, < Jazda12-14>], 
                      "tuesday":[ < Jazda8-10>, < Jazda10-12>, < Jazda13-15>] ... 
                       "friday": ... }

This is class method

```
def min_jazdy_made(self):
    list_of_students = []

    # Counting how many jazdy is in schedule
    for day, jazdy in self.dict_schedule.items():
        for jazda in jazdy:
            if jazda.student in list_of_students:
                DEBUG(debugging, ("id student", id(jazda.student), "student", list_of_students[-1]) )
                #jazda.student.jazdy += 1                                          <--- this doesnt work, it creates error
                list_of_students[list_of_students.index(jazda.student)].jazdy += 1 <--- this works (2)
            else:
                list_of_students.append(jazda.student) <--- is here the copy being made?
                list_of_students[-1].jazdy = 1         <--- i am creating atribute
                DEBUG(debugging, ("id student", id(list_of_students[-1]), "student", list_of_students[-1]) )

    # Checking if it meets requirements
    for student in self.students_ls:
        if student in list_of_students:
            if not student.jazdy >= student.min_jazdy:  <--- if I use (2) error comes in here
                return False, student
        else:
            if student.min_jazdy > 0:
                return False, student

    return True, None
```

#### Output:

```
new_models.py:225 min_jazdy_made | id student 54223632 student <J.D. Student nr 0>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54223752 student <J.D. Student nr 0>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54223872 student <J.D. Student nr 0>
new_models.py:225 min_jazdy_made | id student 54223992 student <J.D. Student nr 1>
new_models.py:225 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224112 student <J.D. Student nr 7>
new_models.py:225 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224232 student <J.D. Student nr 5>
new_models.py:225 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224352 student <J.D. Student nr 2>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224472 student <J.D. Student nr 2>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224592 student <J.D. Student nr 2>
new_models.py:225 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224712 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224832 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54224952 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54225072 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54225192 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54225312 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 54225432 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
new_models.py:218 min_jazdy_made | id student 20768224 student <J.D. Student nr 6>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Code\Python\projects\generator_rozkladow\rozklady_jazd\main_gen.py", line 52, in <module>
    full_sched = sched.recursive_schedule_maker(level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Code\Python\projects\generator_rozkladow\rozklady_jazd\new_models.py", line 511, in recursive_schedule_maker
    ret = self.recursive_schedule_maker( **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Code\Python\projects\generator_rozkladow\rozklady_jazd\new_models.py", line 511, in recursive_schedule_maker
    ret = self.recursive_schedule_maker( **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Code\Python\projects\generator_rozkladow\rozklady_jazd\new_models.py", line 511, in recursive_schedule_maker
    ret = self.recursive_schedule_maker( **kwargs)
  [Previous line repeated 15 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Code\Python\projects\generator_rozkladow\rozklady_jazd\new_models.py", line 455, in recursive_schedule_maker
    if schedule_out.evaluate_self()!=False:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Code\Python\projects\generator_rozkladow\rozklady_jazd\new_models.py", line 254, in evaluate_self
    BOOL, student = self.min_jazdy_made()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Code\Python\projects\generator_rozkladow\rozklady_jazd\new_models.py", line 229, in min_jazdy_made
    if not student.jazdy >= student.min_jazdy:
AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'jazdy'
```

I want to access `.jazdy` atribuute from object that would be `appended` to list and from an object that came in `jazda.student.jazda`,

How do I do that?

Comment: Does your `Student` class have an `__eq__` method? If so, what does it say?

Comment: yeah i made one, it checks name, students id number and names

Comment: and there I think is the problem - see my answer

Comment: I think you can replace the entire first loop with something like `counts = Counter(j.student for jazdy in self.dict_schedule.values() for j in jazdy)`.

Comment: shoud I get rid of ```__eq__``` and use something else to compare them?

Comment: Why do you even need a comparison operator? You should only instantiate `Student` once for each actual student that you want to represent, and all instances of `Student` would therefore be **not** equal, as is the default if you do not create `__eq__`. Check your inputs, because I think that you are creating multiple instances before the code shown in the question is reached.

Comment: However you are populating `self.dict_schedule`, you need to check if you have an _existing_ `Student` instance that already represents the student you are dealing with, and if you do, use that instead of creating another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that would create any copies of `Student` objects, only references to them.

Here is what I suspect is happening:

- your *input* (in `self.dict_schedule`) already contains multiple instances of each student (e.g. "J.D. Student nr 0") for some reason
- you have code in a comparison method (`Student.__eq__`) which means that these copies are being treated as being equal
- the `if jazda.student in list_of_students` is finding not the exact object pointed to by `jazda.student`, but another one on the list which is equal to it
- therefore the `jazda.student.jadzy` is not being initialised because `list_of_students[list_of_students.index(jazda.student)]` is pointing to a different object from `jazda.student`

The behaviour of `in` (and `index`) in relation to objects which are distinct but equal can be seen by this example:

```
>>> lst = [10, 20]

>>> 20.0 in lst
True

>>> lst.index(20.0)
1

>>> 20.0 is 20
False

>>> 20.0 == 20
True
```

Comment: To create every possibe schedule and find the best one I use minimax algorithm, I have to use ```deepcopy(schedule)```, ```copy(schedule)``` didnt work,  does ```deepcopy``` also copy atributes?

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem in deed. While i couldnt figure out a neet way to copy schedule Objects while keeping atributes referenced. I used dict to count how many jazdy they have. I assigned key to Students id.